# About Web API access and authentication

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, webapi

I want to build an API using node.js that will require getting data from another API service. The API service uses grant of Authorization code.

I don't need the users to have access credentials to the API service. I want to use my credentials to pull the data from the API service and present the filtered data to the end-user.
How can I use Oauth2.0 for this purpose?

Comment: save your credentials in an environment variable on your backend, add them to the API request.

Comment: 'I don't need the users to have access credentials to the API service' why?